# Javascript Immutability: deep copy dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-redux, immutability

I'm using react-redux and I'd like to deep-copy the redux state.

For example, I have the following state

state = {
teststate: 0,
number: {
testnumber1: 10,
testnumber2: 20
}
}

In this case, I'd like to change the value of **testnumber1**.

I'd tried like this, but this doesn't work.

Object.assign( {}, state, {testnumber1: 30} }

How can I make change in testnumber1 value?

Comment: numbers format is invalid. it's neither an array nor an object

Comment: Since the state example in your question isn't even valid JavaScript it is not possible to anwer your question. Is number an array or an object literal? You can read how to update state [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), if you use a library I'd suggest immer as that comes with the standard redux template application.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. I edited my state

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.assign` you could do

```js
state = { teststate: 0, number: { testnumber1: 10, testnumber2: 20 } }
var newobject={teststate:state.teststate,number:Object.assign({},state.number)}
var assign=Object.assign(newobject.number,{testnumber1:30})
console.log(newobject)
console.log(state)
```

Comment: I'd tried this. It works but subscribe method doesn't work(it doesn't change the value).

I'd like to know the difference between these two(I think your solution only change the value. not creating new value).

Would you mind please come here and see my code?

My code is in store.js.

link: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/0715-logintest-2o7y7?file=/src/store.js

Comment: do you mean you want a new object with new values ?

Comment: I have updated the code, let me know if it works for you

Comment: @Sven.hig `Object.assign(state.number,{testnumber1:30})` mutates state, try to log state as well.

Comment: @HMR thank you for let me know, I have fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

We'd better not mutate the state directly instead of returning a cloned state.
You can either use map to convert the array or use splice to get a new array to replace old one.

```js
const state = { teststate: 0, number: [ {testnumber1: 10}, {testnumber2: 20}, {testnumber3: 40} ] }
const newNumber = state.number.map(n => {
  if(Object.keys(n).toString() === 'testnumber1'){
    return {testnumber1 : 30};
  }
  return n;
});
const newState = {...state, number : newNumber};
console.log("\n newState\n", newState);
console.log("\n state\n", state);
```